# How to separate Numbers from field data?

Tags: apex, formula-field

I have a field called Name. The Value of Name field is like 1001PAIO or 100PAJK. 
I need to divide the Name field into 3 fields.

One field should have only Numbers I.e first 3 or 4 digits

Second field should have two letters of Text Next to Numbers.

Third field should have last Two letters

If the Name is 1001PAIO then three field should be like below

Ex:

```
  Field one : 100

  Field Two : PA

  Field Three : IO
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do this. Which functions should I use.

Comment: Why have you included both apex and formula-field tags? The answers you'll get for one won't work with the other. Which approach would you prefer? Also, what research have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex, it simplifies things and stops you from doing String manipulation. The important bit to know is the use of [capturing group](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_capturing_groups.htm)

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('([0-9]{3,4})([A-Z]{2})([A-Z]{2})');
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher('1001PAIO');
MyMatcher.hitEnd();
if(MyMatcher.matches()){
    System.debug(MyMatcher.group(1) );//1001
    System.debug(MyMatcher.group(2) );//PA
    System.debug(MyMatcher.group(3) );//IO
}
```

src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_example.htm

Comment: Do I need to write Apex class for this?

Comment: Didnt you add apex tag in your question?

Comment: Yes Jaiswal. Can you please tell me where to execute this to update three fields?

Comment: I tried with REGEX( Name__c, ‘([0-9]{3-4})’) for first field in formula field but it is giving.                       

Function REGEX may not be used in this type of formula

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your custom function with contents similar to this:

```
String originalString = '100PAJK';
Integer firstLetter = -1;
Integer startInteger = '0'.getChars()[0];
Integer endInteger = '9'.getChars()[0];

List<Integer> chars = originalString.getChars();
for (Integer i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++) {
    if (!(chars[i] >= startInteger && chars[i] <= endInteger)) { //check if character is numeric
        firstLetter = i;
        break;
    }
}

Map<String, Object> ans = new Map<String, String>{
        'field_one' => originalString.substring(0, firstLetter),
        'field_two' => originalString.substring(firstLetter, originalString.length() - 2),
        'field_three' => originalString.substring(originalString.length() - 2)
};

system.debug(ans);
```